# Deleting specific remote commits after pull request

Tags: git, github

Recently I merged a branch into master through a pull request and then found out some of the files in some of the commits of that branch are not needed on remote, so I was thinking deleting those files only in those commits. But it wasn't that easy so I decided to just simply delete those commits as I thought pull request for that branch has already been merged.

After fiddling with `git rebase HEAD^^` etc, I only end up moving the head of the branch, not deleting those commits, as I suspect master still relies on the whole branch so git doesn't do what I wanted.

Any thoughts? Or, any better way to resolve my problem?

--- After edit

Below is the ascii art of my example. So, to elaborate a bit more, the *branch* was now merged into M5 through pull request, and I was thinking deleting some of the files in commit B2 and B3, but then thought it would be easier to delete B2 and B3 and failed to do so. Now the HEAD of *branch* is B2, not B4 anymore.

```
     B1 -- B2 -- B3 -- B4           (branch)
    /                    \
-- M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4 -- M5 -- M6 (master)
```

So far below are the commands I have run to get to this stage

1. when HEAD of *branch* was B4, I did `git rebase -i HEAD^^`.
2. I removed `pick <message of B4>` and `pick <message of B3>` line.
3. and now the HEAD is B2. However, B3 and B4 are still there as if `git rebase` wasn't run.

--- Edit

Best regards,
Tidus

Comment: Can you describe what your current history looks like? Check out other git questions here on stack overflow to see common ways of visualizing a git repository with ASCII art.

Comment: One solution is to delete the files and make a new commit. The files will still remain in the commit history, though, which shouldn't be a problem unless they are large or contain sensitive information.

Comment: If you can reproduce the situation with a short sequence of commands, starting from an empty repo, that would be helpful too. That would give us a [mcve]. Right now it's hard to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your comment there. It does contain sensitive information and that's the problem.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your comment. Does my post now make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to keep commit `B4` but remove `B2` and `B3`. I also assume you want to keep `M6` on `master`. One way to do this is first edit `branch`. Start by moving `branch` back to `B4`:

```
git checkout branch
git reset --hard B4
```

(Note that in all of the commands in my answer, you should replace commit references such as `B4` with an actual SHA1 hash.)

Next remove `B2` and `B3`

```
git rebase -i M1
```

This command will open your text editor with a file where you can edit the commands for each commit. For `B2` and `B3`, mark them with `s` for "skip".

Next create a temporary branch in order to keep track of `M6` and reset `master` to before the merge:

```
git checkout master
git branch temp
git reset --hard M4
```

Now merge again:

```
git merge branch
```

Finally, get `M6` back on master:

```
git cherry-pick M6
```

Technically, the `temp` branch isn't necessary as you can find the hash for `M6` with reflog or make not of it before resetting master. Creating `temp` just makes it easier to keep track of what you are doing.

There also might be more efficient ways to do what you want with something like `git filter-branch`, but it is also more complicated coming up with the exact command. Personally I find it easier to combine tools like `git reset`, `git rebase`, and `git cherry-pick` to get the result I want instead of going for doing it all with a single command.

Note that if you make a mistake at any time, you can use `git reflog` to view a history of your most recent commands. This also shows the SHA1 hashes of commits you have checked out recently so that you can get back to them easily.